# How do I get Kapp'n to stop serenading me?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So when I first unlocked Tortimer's Island and took the first trip with Kapp'n, he asked me whether or not I wanted him to sing a song on the way or not. Seeing as it was my first trip, and I was heading to the Island with some friends, I figured why not have some entertainment.

This has now become somewhat of an annoyance. Sometimes I just want to get to the island quickly to do some fishing or bug catching, and I want to do it as quickly as possible so I can get back before shops close and pay off some of my loan. Is there any way I can get Kapp'n to stop singing each time we set sail?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying out some random button mashing out of frustration and doing some research to confirm my findings, there *is* a way to skip the songs and go straight to or from the island.

Once he starts singing, you can either press <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd> repeatedly (I tested and both buttons work, not just <kbd>B</kbd>, as many sites report), or rapidly tap on the touchscreen and he'll stop singing.

He'll also guilt you a little about skipping his song, but that has no effect on gameplay.

Comment: Note you can hold B while he complains and the game will transition even faster to the landing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make him stop singing.

Press the B button or A button once he starts singing the song, or rapidly tap on the Touch screen and then he can stop singing.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. This information is already in the accepted answer. Can you provide some additional information?

Answer (score -2):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for:

http://www.theitcommunity.com/wiki/Skip_Kapp%27n_song_in_Animal_Crossing_New_Leaf

Comment: Hi, Ittuh, and welcome to Arqade!  Please don't leave link only answers, as we don't want to deal with link rot down the road.  Keep the link as a source, but add all the steps required to solve the problem to your answer.